# Global Java Type Adapters in MOXy

Tags: java, json, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

Is it possible to define global java type adapters/converters in MOXy (up to the newest release (2.6.0)?
Such adapter would be applied by default to all classes registered in jaxb context if not explicitly overridden.

For instance, I would like to add support for all Joda Time types which would require neither a `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` at a field nor a class nor a package level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filed a bug for this.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=478404

Workaround I currently use:
Create OXM bindings configuration dynamically at runtime and save it in memory as a String. Then feed it to MOXy via "eclipselink.oxm.metadata-source" property, using StringReaders.

Answer (score 3):

As workaround it's possible to wrap all needed instances with some custom type:

```
public class MyJodaTime {
  @XmlValue    
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(JodaTimeAdapter.class)    
  public DateTime value;
}
```